# Having issue with UITextView drag and drop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am trying to drag a `UITextView` object with touch ! but I have a problem , I need when user touches the `custom view` , the touching event begins, but touching methods works only on `self.view` . here is my code :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     NSLog(@"touch began ");

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    startingX = [touch locationInView:_captureView].x;
    startingY = [touch locationInView:_captureView].y;
}




- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{



    CGPoint currentPoint = _mText.frame.origin;

    float xForView, yForView;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    float newX = [touch locationInView:_captureView].x;
    float deltaX;


    if(startingX > newX){
        deltaX = startingX - newX;
        xForView = currentPoint.x - deltaX;
    } else if(newX > startingX){
        deltaX = newX - startingX;
        xForView = currentPoint.x + deltaX;
    } else xForView = currentPoint.x;


    float newY = [touch locationInView:_captureView].y;
    float deltaY;

    if(startingY > newY){
        deltaY = startingY - newY;
        yForView = currentPoint.y - deltaY;
    } else if(newY > startingY){
        deltaY = newY - startingY;
        yForView = currentPoint.y + deltaY;
    } else yForView = currentPoint.y;



    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(xForView, yForView, _mText.frame.size.width, _mText.frame.size.height);
    _mText.frame = newFrame;

    startingX = newX;
    startingY = newY;
}
```

my textView is not **editable** all views are `userInteractionEnabled`

Comment: touchesBegan, touchesMoved methods are called when you subclass the UIView. you have to subclass the View

Comment: @SunnyShah sorry I don't get it ! ?

Answer (score 0):

Write your `touches began` method and `touches moved` method inside the your custom text view and try to adjust the frame.

Comment: the custom view is just a UIView not ViewController !